# MYSQL: Regex substituion

Tags: mysql, regex

So Im going to try and explain what Im trying to accomplish.

I'm looking to copy a string from FIELD1 to FIELD2, make it uppercase, and depending on the value of another field (FIELD3: yes/no), either prepend "HOST-" or append "-NET" to FIELD2. Also, this also only needs to affect entries whose FIELD4 value is "bar".

So for example FIELD1 contains the text "foo" and its Host value is "yes". FIELD2 should read "HOST-FOO".

For FIELD3 value "no", FIELD2 would read "FOO-NET".

My coworker and I were talking about this and he believes this can be accomplished via regex. Am I in the right ballpark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly your question i think is more simple use CASE

```
select case field3 when 'yes' then concat( 'HOST-' . field1)
                   when 'no' then concat( field1 .'-NET')  
       END as Field2 
from my_tbale 
where field4 = 'bar';
```

Comment: This appears as it should work, though it only needs to occur when FIELD4 is "bar". I need to let you know, Im out of my area with MySQL. This statement will not alter the string in FIELD1 correct? Would it at all be helpful if I tried to explain the logic via Java? I tend to think more logically that way!

Comment: I have update the aswer .  .. this query don't alter the value in column1 ..and if you are using a select you don't need the convert in java but use directly the result ..

Comment: One last question, is it also possible to check if FIELD1 already begins/ends with 'HOST-' or '-NET' so I'm not doubling up?

Comment: Yes .. of course .. you can add the check in where clasue ...eg: and (left( filed1,5)  != 'HOST-'  AND  right(filed1,4) !='-NET')